# Stuck on getting access token for Credit Card (paypal)

Tags: api, rest

I am working on an application which uses Paypal REST API for payments.
I have a client ID & secret but when I try to fetch the access token I get the following error message-

**Invalid HTTP response The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send**

What could be the problem? please suggest.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this. The version of Newtonsoft.JSON was not compatible with paypal rest API & the webconfig on server was not updated with the package includes.